# Magento2 - Multistore/domain export one website import in fresh install

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, import, importexport, export

I was wondering if it is possible to export a whole website (Including blocks, widgets, products, etc. which are enabled for that specific website)

Lets say you have a multistore/domain setup which contains website A and website B.

Website A belongs to company X and website B belongs to company Y.

Company X and company Y broke up with each other, and they want to split the multi store in 2 seperate installs. But they want to keep their blocks, widgets, products, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the unwanted website from each other's servers.

1. Install the system on two separate servers.
2. Login to site X and delete site Y from there.
3. Login to site Y and delete site X from there.

Comment: Nice! Wondering why I didn't taught about this... :)